# Use lodash to delete an element from an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

Assuming I have the data below, I am trying to determine how to remove the message object that has notice_id = 3. I can't figure out how to remove an individual message. Is it possible?

```
 var newMockData = [
               {"date": "JAN 18 2016", 
                "messages": [{
                    "notice_id": "1",
                    "notice_title": "Bad news",
                    "notice_text": "Server is down!",
                    "start_date": "2016-09-18T04:00:00Z"
                  },
                  {
                    "notice_id": "2",
                    "notice_title": "Weekly Reminder",
                    "notice_text": "Please read the assignment!",
                    "start_date": "2016-09-18T04:00:00Z"
                  }]
                },
                {"date": "JAN 19 2016", 
                "messages": [{
                    "notice_id": "3",
                    "notice_title": "Sweet",
                    "notice_text": "This morning, the new edition of our blog hit stands!",
                    "start_date": "2016-09-19T04:00:00Z"
                  },
                  {
                    "notice_id": "4",
                    "notice_title": "Yeah",
                    "notice_text": "This is pretty cool",
                    "start_date": "2016-09-19T04:00:00Z"
                  }]

               }
            ]
```

Comment: of course its possible, what have you tried? _.filter might be good here

Comment: Not sure you have to use lodash. The [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method works without a library...

Comment: I though I was getting close with the following, but I believe I am off. _.filter(newMockData , {messages: [{notice_id : noticeid}]}); @JordanHendrix

Comment: I am sorry, can you tell me what you mean by the message are lost? @Andreas

Comment: @Andreas I have edified to show it as an array of of two objects. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just loop through the array and use [**remove**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#remove) on the `messages` array:

```
_.forEach(newMockData, function (el) {
  _.remove(el.messages, { notice_id: '3'});
});
```

```js
var newMockData = [{ 
  "date": "JAN 18 2016", 
  "messages": [{
    "notice_id": "1",
    "notice_title": "Bad news",
    "notice_text": "Server is down!",
    "start_date": "2016-09-18T04:00:00Z"
  },{
    "notice_id": "2",
    "notice_title": "Weekly Reminder",
    "notice_text": "Please read the assignment!",
    "start_date": "2016-09-18T04:00:00Z"
  }]
},{
  "date": "JAN 19 2016", 
  "messages": [{
    "notice_id": "3",
    "notice_title": "Sweet",
    "notice_text": "This morning, the new edition of our blog hit stands!",
    "start_date": "2016-09-19T04:00:00Z"
  },{
    "notice_id": "4",
    "notice_title": "Yeah",
    "notice_text": "This is pretty cool",
    "start_date": "2016-09-19T04:00:00Z"
  }]
}];

_.forEach(newMockData, function (el) {
 _.remove(el.messages, { notice_id: '3' });
});

console.log(newMockData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS `map()` and `filter()` (or their lodash's equivalents) to create a new array without the message, and without mutating the original data:

```js
 function removeMessage(data, messageId) {
   return data.map(function(item) {
     return item.messages.filter(function(message) {
       return message.notice_id !== messageId;
     });
   });
 }

 var newMockData = [{
   "date": "JAN 18 2016",
   "messages": [{
     "notice_id": "1",
     "notice_title": "Bad news",
     "notice_text": "Server is down!",
     "start_date": "2016-09-18T04:00:00Z"
   }, {
     "notice_id": "2",
     "notice_title": "Weekly Reminder",
     "notice_text": "Please read the assignment!",
     "start_date": "2016-09-18T04:00:00Z"
   }]
 }, {
   "date": "JAN 19 2016",
   "messages": [{
     "notice_id": "3",
     "notice_title": "Sweet",
     "notice_text": "This morning, the new edition of our blog hit stands!",
     "start_date": "2016-09-19T04:00:00Z"
   }, {
     "notice_id": "4",
     "notice_title": "Yeah",
     "notice_text": "This is pretty cool",
     "start_date": "2016-09-19T04:00:00Z"
   }]

 }];

 var result = removeMessage(newMockData, '3');

 console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```